Is it possible to access records created in another record-triggered flow batch from invocable apex action
There is a record-triggered flow that is launched when A records are created.
A collection of B records is created in the flow.
After that, I will call the invocable apex action in the flow.
Inside the invocable apex action, I create C records, but I need to take into account all the B records created in the flow and the already existing C records.
Since the invocable apex action is a balkified element, like a DML operation, or SOQL, I will be able to send there, as an input parameter, the created collections of B records from all "flows interview".
But the record-triggered flow processes records in batches, the batch size is 200 records. I need to think of an option where more than 200 A records are created and, accordingly, several batches of the record-triggered flow will be launched.
Thus, my question is: will I be able to access (using SOQL, for example) those C records that are created in another batch inside the invocable apex action?
Thanks in advance
UPD!
All the records described here are on one org. And all their processing occurs there.

If the records are in the "database", then, yes, you'll be able to access them. It's unclear from your verbal description whether this is or isn't the case. See Order of Execution for more info

If I understand correctly, the database is salesforce org. All the records in question are on org. And all their processing occurs there. So the answer, I think, - yes, everything is in the database.
